# sscanf with letters, spaces and integers

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use sscanf to read a line from a text file and then save the parts of it to the different variables.
The text file looks like that:

```
name 12345
```

So I've written the following code:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", name, &number);
```

which works great, but what do I do when name has a space in between? e.g.

```
name lastname 12345
```

Or even number?

```
name the3rd 12345
```

My sscanf won't work in those two examples. I tried to use the [^] without success or even %*s %[^0-9] %d but didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please note that the format descriptor string used with `sscanf()` and friends is *not* in any way a regular expression. It might look similiar (if you squint, and in dubious lighting conditions), but it's really really not a regular expression. It's specific to those functions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info! updated the question header and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not trying to force a solution upon the problem. If it's hard with `sscanf()`, perhaps that's not the proper solution.

I would instead recommend either using an actual regular expression (if you have `<regexp.h>` it's easy), or using manual parsing techniques to find the last space and splitting the string on that. It can be as easy as `strrchr(buffer, ' ');` after all.